# Is it Possible to Understand Road Signs in Taiwan with Only Knowing Latin Characters?

Tags: driving, taiwan

Some parts of Taiwan that I would like to see are easier to cover by car, so I am seriously considering renting a car for part of my stay there. I've never driving in a place where the signs are not written with latin characters, so I Googled *Taiwan road signs*. This gave me an [easy one to guess](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Taiwan_road_sign_%E9%81%B51.svg), but also [some](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Taiwan_road_sign_Art060.4.png/220px-Taiwan_road_sign_Art060.4.png) that I have [no clue](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Taiwan_road_sign_Art059.png) about. I can see that road names appear to be written with latin characters.

**Are there many different signs that are unintelligible to people who can only recognize latin letters?**

Comment: From the shapes, it looks like you've linked to stop, checkpoint, and yield signs. Are these not used in your country?

Comment: The stop was easy to guess. We do not have checkpoint signs, so this is a new one, nor have I ever noticed one elsewhere. Yield we have too but I was not sure it is the same. Even in Europe, some signs are baffling for Canadians.

Comment: FWIW, there is a document, the [Vienna Convention on
Road Signs](https://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/trans/conventn/Conv_road_signs_2006v_EN.pdf), which attempts to set international standards for road signs. It is up to each country to choose which among these to adopt and enforce, however. Wikipedia has a useful [comparison of European road signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_European_road_signs) and a [comparison of MUTCD-influenced road signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MUTCD-influenced_traffic_signs), the latter mostly in the Americas and the Pacific.

Comment: @choster That's a very good resource! There are plenty of signs there that I have never seen. Worse though are a few completely non-intuitive ones, such as *Give way to oncoming traffic*, *priority road* (no idea what it even means). In Canada or Ecuador (where I live now), we have none of these, not even the no-parking and no-stopping signs shown.

Comment: @Choster Checkpoint? As in, if you crash, you respawn there?

Comment: How is this opinion-based? Does understanding Taiwanese road signs involve recognizing the Chinese characters, or can one do it from knowledge of the shapes and other graphic elements? Seems like a pretty straightforward "yes" or "no" question, to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taiwan uses the same road traffic signs, as are used in most Asian, European and African countries. You can find plenty of lists, examples and explanations of these on the internet. The meaning of a traffic sign must be obvious without knowing the local language. Any text on the sign should only provide additional details, which are not necessary to understand, to comply with the basic definition of the sign.

The three signs you are linking to have the following meanings:

- The [stop sign](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Taiwan_road_sign_%E9%81%B51.svg) is a red octagon, optionally with 'stop' (or similar in local language) written on it. It means that you have to stop the vehicle completely before entering the junction and yield for crossing traffic. It is the only sign with this shape.
- The [yield sign](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Taiwan_road_sign_Art059.png) is an upside down, white triangle with a red border. It means that you have to yield for crossing traffic, but are not required to stop completely before entering the junction. It is the only sign with this shape.
- The [prohibiton of passing without stopping sign](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Taiwan_road_sign_Art060.4.png/220px-Taiwan_road_sign_Art060.4.png) is a white circle with a thick, horizontal black line in the middle and a red border. The sign usually has additional text explaining the reason for why you have to stop (in your example it is a weight control), but even without understanding the text or the specific reason, you know that you for some reason are required to stop. The basic shape of this sign (white circle with red border) identifies it as a prohibition sign. Usually a pictogram in the sign tells you what is prohibited.

Some countries use yellow instead of white as the background colour on their road signs.

So to answer your question: No, there should not be any road signs in Taiway, which are unintelligible to people who can only recognize latin letters.

Comment: Good to know. I had not much trouble in Europe but I did encounter some signs that I did not know what to do with. In Denmak for example they have one which says the speed limit is NOT a certain velocity but it does not say what the new limit is! Parking signs are a whole other issue though.

Comment: Most European countries have default speed limits, e.g. for built-up areas, country roads and motorways (in Denmark: 50, 80 and 130km/h). Speed limits are then only designated if they deviate from the default limit. Revoking a designated speed limit (as you have seen) means that the default speed limit comes into force.